# Am I getting this error because I'm using SSO? "Error loading state: AccessDenied: Access Denied status code: 403"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, terraform, single-sign-on, terraform-provider-aws

This is my terraform set up. When I used an Access Key and a Secret Key in a different account, I had no problems initializing terraform. But now that I'm using SSO with this account, I get this error:

Error loading state:
AccessDenied: Access Denied
status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxxx

Then I found this in a terraform document. Not sure if I understand this correctly, but am I getting this error because I am using SSO? If so, what do I need to do to fix this and get terraform to work with this account.

"Please note that the AWS Go SDK, the underlying authentication handler used by the Terraform AWS Provider, does not support all AWS CLI features, such as Single Sign On (SSO) configuration or credentials."

Note: "my-bucket" was previously created in this account using the CLI.

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
    profile = "XXXXX"    
}

terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.13.0"
   backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "mykey"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having this exact same issue with terraform and sso, will update if I find solution. * Update, in my case it was because the state bucket had an explicit deny for unencrypted transfers. I added `encrypt = true` to my tfstate backend and it worked fine. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#s3-state-storage

Comment: My bucket is very basic, no encryption at this point. I have no problems initializing when I use the Access Key and Secret Key but I cannot initialize it when using SSO.

Comment: You also want to make sure you are using aws provider version 3.27.0 or higher

Answer (score 0):

If you had access keys set prior to configuring AWS SSO, you have to unset both AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and set AWS_PROFILE instead then it should work correctly.

```
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_PROFILE=[profile-name-here]
```

In my case I am using CDKTF so I also had to update the AWS provider to reference a shared config

```
AwsProvider(self, "aws", region=region, shared_config_files=["~/.aws/config"], profile=aws_profile)
```

Then, your AWS config profile should include the `sso_region` and `sso_start_url`

I can confirm this works with for following version
`"hashicorp/aws@~> 5.12"`, `aws-cli/2.13.9`,  `Python/3.11.4`